# What to do when the sum of probabilities is greater than one?

Tags: probability

I have this problem. Imagine that somebody will pay after I contact him by sending an email, text message, letter, or calling him. I have the probability of how likely he will pay after being approached with one of the mentioned methods.

The sum of these probabilities is greater than one. How can I transform them so that the sum is less than or equal one?

Comment: Cannot happen. Probabilities are between 0 and 1. Maybe you have a normalization problem.

Comment: If their sum is $s$, then divide each by $s$ such that their sum is $1$.

Comment: There is no reason why those probabilities should add to $1$ or less.  Maybe the fellow will always play however he is contacted.  Then each conditional probability is $1$ so the sum is $3$.  No problem.

Comment: The need that their sum is one is coming from the expected return that I can get by multiplying the probability by the amount of money that they owe to me.

Comment: I think that this formula might be the solution P(A) + P(B) - P(A∩B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that these are not probabilities of mutually exclusive events. When rolling a die, you can take the probability of rolling a 1 and add it to the probability of rolling a 2 to get the probability of rolling a 1 or 2, but only because getting a 1 and getting a 2 are mutually exclusive events.

Suppose the person has a 50% chance of paying after being approached with any of the methods - the probability of them paying after a text or after an email is *not* the probability of them paying after a text plus the probability of them paying after an email, since them paying after a text and them paying after an email are not mutually exclusive - they may pay after both a text and an email.

You need joint probabilities describing the probability of payment given multiple approaches. Unfortunately, there is no way to go from marginal univariate probabilities to the joint probabilities for arbitrary probability distributions. If both text and email are 50% effective individually, they together could have as little as 50% effectiveness (if they cover the same 50%), or as much as 100% (if they cover completely distinct halves). The person may respond to both or neither method in the first case, or one method but not the other in the second.

Without knowing more about what kind of "overlap" is involved in the joint probabilities, summing the individual probabilities and transforming them is meaningless. The formula mentioned in the comments is the correct way of accounting for non-exclusive events - rather than just summing the probability of paying after a text and the probability of paying after an email, you also need to subtract the "double counted" part, which is the probability of paying after a text *and* an email.

Comment: Thanks for your help